# Does Facebook maintain a whitelist of domains whose content displays differently when shared to a Timeline?

Tags: facebook, flash, video, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

In all of my testing it seems that Facebook treats Youtube & Vimeo's video embeds differently than our own. Specifically, when a video link/embed is shared to the Timeline and set to the full-width 2-column display, the image specified via og:image is **still shown as a scaled-down thumbnail** (as it does in the 1-column display mode), and the og:description occupies the rest of the space to the right.

This is in direct contrast to Youtube & Vimeo embed shares, which instead display the og:description above (full-width), and the **scaled-up og:image below, also full-width**.

I've tried to replicate as much as their Open Graph tags as possible, including similar image and video dimensions, ordering, etc, but in every instance it never seems to treat our embeds quite the same. I used the FB URL linter to break cache after each test, and to make sure it's pulling my OG tags properly.

Observations:

- When the video dimensions **are** specified, FB tries to scale the video embed down as necessary to fit a smaller available space (Timeline 1-column display).
- When the video dimensions are **not** specified, FB tries to scale the video embed up **or** down to fit the full available space (both 1-column Timeline and wider 2-column Timeline).
- Listing multiple og:images of varying sizes (each with their own og:image:width and height specified) does not seem to have any effect on displaying differently based on context; FB always grabs the first one specified, and scales it up/down as needed for thumbnails, news ticker, timeline 1- and 2-column, etc.
- Specifying the og:type as 'article' -- as Vimeo does -- does not seem to have any effect on the embed display. It displays it the same as if it was rightfully specified as 'video' or 'video.movie'.
- Specifying image dimensions via og:image:width and height do not seem to have any observable effect (compared to **not** specifying them).

Anyone have any insights? It seems FB's implementation of Open Graph tags for video shares have changed quite a bit with the recent introduction of Timeline, but their documentation does not reflect the changes, nor how they are best used for display in the Timeline.

Comment: The whole business of video embeds in Timeline or Wall has become really buggy since Timeline was introduced. Facebook handles the URLs differently on the wall, on the feed, and on timeline. Plus there's a known-bug with their Open-Graph scraper (confirmed to me by Cloudflare).